# How do I listen to onClick events for a Bootstrap modal button using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this JavaScript, but the event is never firing.

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#emailButton').click(function() {
        console.log("emailButton()...");
```

The HTML is

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Email Page to a Friend" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailModal" id="#emailButton">
```

The modal pops up, but the click handler isn't working. Nothing shows up in the console. Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y59qys4j/8/

Comment: `id="#emailButton"` - there should not be a `#` in the id attribute of the button - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y59qys4j/10/

Comment: @ArunPJohny his id has that `#`

Comment: just remove # in id of button

Comment: @guradio it is a typo.... so we could just close it

Comment: @uzaif his id includes that `#`

Comment: @guradio `$('#emailButton')` is a valid id selector, where the id attribute value itself does not have `#` in it

Comment: @guradio If the id is `id="#emailButton"` then the selector should be `$('#\\#emailButton')`

Comment: $("button[data-toggle='modal']").click(function() {
  console.log("emailButton()...");
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the # from your id in the html:

```
id="emailButton"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/y59qys4j/11/

Answer (score 0):

When you're defining the button, you use:

```
id="#emailButton"
```

when you need:

```
id="emailButton"
```

"#" is only used in CSS to indicate when an id is being selected, and shouldn't be included when defining the id in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it. I added a hash in the `id` field. But what's really strange is that I uses Chrome's console to view the object, and it returned a value!

```
$('#emailButton')
j…y.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#emailButton"}


$('#emailButton')
[<button type=​"button" class=​"btn btn-default" title=​"Email Page to a Friend" data-toggle=​"modal" data-target=​"#emailModal" id=​"emailButton">​…​</button>​]
```

However, now I see they return different results.